# TextView ? How to scale it or something

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

Sup guys, i got a problem with TextView placed on RelativeLayout with background, i have added the textView's with my font to my "game" when i turn on application on GS3 everything looks nice, but when start it on Galaxy Mini (lower resolution) the textView isn't scalling right.
is there any option to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size of the text in sp.

Example

```
android:textsize="12sp"
```

> sp Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also
>   scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use
>   this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
>   both the screen density and user's preference.

Comment: well it didn help, the text size is still the same and the GAME OVER text view needs 2 lines on galaxy mini when on GS3 it need only one line